# Real time data streaming in xmpp ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am configuring an ejabberd xmpp server for remote streaming of real-time graph data. The implementation is successful, but now a lot of performance issues are cropping up.

My requirement is to send around 3000 messages per minute into a mobile network through ejabberd-xmpp and receive it in a desktop application without any considerable delay.

I have altered traffic_shapers in the ejabberd.yml configuration file to very large values and have modified a lot of other traffic limitations and yet a large amount of buffering is happening on the desktop side when tested in low bandwidth.

So, if I am positive that my configuration is correct, what all extensions should be used? In the time I have researched I have found that the following XEP's can be of help:

  **Stream Compression(XEP-138)**

  **Jingle ICE-UDP Transport Method(XEP-176)**

  **Bidirectional-streams Over Synchronous HTTP (BOSH)(XEP-124)**

  **XMPP Over BOSH(XEP-206)**

  **Stream Management(XEP-198)**

But all the research has only increased the number of doubts:

  If I am to implement any of these XEP's, then what all changes to the configuration have to be made?

  How will I have to alter my XML stanza accordingly? The XEP documentations are surprisingly inadequate for a rookie.

  What is the difference between Stream Management and Stream Compression?

  What is the difference between XMPP Over BOSH and Bidirectional-streams Over Synchronous HTTP?

  How to implement BOSH? I am using port number 5222 now, what all changes to my project will come if I use port 5280? Where all should I reflect these changes?

  If I am to combine any two extensions, will it only increase the speed issue or will it be in my favour?

Please, if anybody can help? I do realize that this question is out of the question spectrum that can be posted on this site and also as the guidelines specify, 'out of scope' and 'off topic'. But any help will be immensely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the negotiation order followed by Ejabberd. Ejabberd follows stream negotiation in this order:
**-TLS

-Stream Compression

-SASL

-Resource Binding**


whilst all the other clients and libraries follow the Recommended Order for Stream Negotiation [XEP-170](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0170.html/):
**-TLS

-SASL

-Stream Compression

-Resource Binding**


This leads to the `<compress>` request to be completely ignored by the ejabberd server after SASL encryption. Since the XEP-170 is identified by the XMPP document keyword RECOMMENDED and not REQUIRED, there is no strict enforcement
 
Although the supported protocols [here](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/) specify that XEP-170 is followed, but I feel that the issue from [this link](http://standards.xmpp.narkive.com/vxzRKUy0/xep-0170-recommended-order-of-stream-feature-negotiation/) which says that "ejabberd 1.1.2: It only accepts compression before SASL (XEP-0138)" is still not fixed 
(Tested the same scenario with OpenFire 3.10, XIFF AS3 library and Seesmic-XMPP AS3 library and compression was happening since OpenFire allows compression before OR after SASL encryption)

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe it seems bandwidth is the issue. Then, stream compression should be useful. Other XEPs will not help you in that situation.

Tip on using Stream compression: When using stream compression, do not forget that after enabling it, all data are send compressed and that they must be uncompressed before being passed to the XML parser.

Comment: Thanks! 
Issue: We are receiving the available methods stanza from the server 
<method>zlib</method>
 but when we send the next request
<compress xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/compress'>
  <method>zlib</method>
</compress>
we are not receiving any response from server. The documentation says that 'If initiating entity did not understand any of the advertised compression methods, it SHOULD ignore the compression option and proceed as if no compression methods were advertised.'  How to fix this? Why is not the server understanding the methods when we have already got the previous response?

Comment: Please, look at ejabberd logs and report. Usually, the response is in the log files.

Comment: Sorry, but the logs did not specify anything about this. I have installed ejabberd using installer in Ubuntu 14.04. Did try using source code, but that installed version 2.1.11 which was not having in built MUC capability. 
Can you suggest anything regarding what all to be done to enable and implement stream management.

Comment: Be careful: Stream management =/= stream compression. I would suggest you try ejabberd 15.11.

Comment: We are using v15.11 now. Same issue. We are following the recommended order for negotiation and are getting all appropriate responses from the server BUT still NOT getting the <compressed> response. We have enabled 'zlib: true' in the configuration. We are getting the <proceed> response after <starttls> request and also the SASL mechanisms response but not the <compressed> response. Checked the logs and it says that 'Application p1_zlib has been started in node ejabberd@localhost'. Compression is the most vital part of our project so if you could please provide more specific information?

Comment: My guess is that your client is not interpreting the result correctly as the result come back compressed. At that precise point your client must uncompress all data received on the socket. From that point all data are send compressed and if you do not uncompress them before XML parsing, your client will not see any meaningful data.

Comment: No sir, you are not understanding my issue. I mean that I am not able to negotiate compression with the server. I am successful in negotiating TLS and SASL but the server is NOT GIVING the <compressed> response when i try to negotiate the zlib compression by <compress xmlns='jabber.org/protocol/compress'><method>zlib</method> </compress>. This is much similar, or should I say the exact same issue as has been stated in https://support.process-one.net/browse/EJAB-1382. Please be specific as I am a newbie in this and would like to contribute to this in the future as well.

Comment: I understand your issue. The compress response is properly returned by ejabberd, but it is compressed already. As it is compressed, you need to be sure that your client is already uncompressing the content. If you do not do that, the client _cannot_ notice the reply as it is trying to parsed compressed content, which is not valid XML. Make sure you use a client library that properly support stream compression and switch to compress data at the right time.

Comment: This is the snippet of my ejabberd.yml. Is this configuration correct if I want to advertise stream compression?
listen:
  - 
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 655536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls: false
    starttls_required: false
    zlib: true
    certfile: "/opt/ejabberd-15.09/conf/server.pem"

If it is correct then, it is just not happening. I am not able to negotiate compression. After TLS and SASL the server jumps straight to resource binding. The <compress> request is simply being ignored by the server.